# How to Install New Relic's php agent on a Dreamhost VPS?

Tags: vps, dreamhost, newrelic

Has anybody found a way to install New Relic's php agent on a Dreamhost VPS?

I changed my default php location to the newest php (5.3). I've also added these lines

```
export NR_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/php53/bin/
export NR_INSTALL_PHPLIST=/usr/local/php53/bin/
```

But the New Relic script keeps defaulting another php version (5.2.17)

Can anybody outthere help me?
**Thanks!**

Comment: Thisi is quite a old post. I also would like some monitoring in place on dreamhost though installing on a VPS should not be a problem. Have you actually tried the instructions in http://newrelic.com/php ?